# Dose Fortran have something like class of Java?

Tags: fortran

I want to implements data structures on Fortran,but it seems there is not something like class of Java.

Module cannot handle more than one data structures.This is very annoying.

Is there something like class of Java?

Comment: *Module cannot handle more than one data structures.*  Nonsense, and you should kick whoever told you that.  You should direct your research at Fortran's `type`s and the topic of *derived types*.  To the extent that I understand them Java's classes approximate those.

Comment: Please explain which exact properties do you want. Fortran experts may not know Java. I know very little of Java, just that it looks similar to C++. What did you study? Did you check Fortran derived types? Did you try to search for "object oriented programming" on the web? Google gives this immediately http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming

Comment: I'm very sorry for ridiculous question.My suvey is totally insufficient.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Fortran are you using? *derived types* should satisfy the requirements of classes.

According to http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming:

> In order to obtain class-like behavior, one can combine a module, which contains the methods that operate on the class, with a derived type containing the data. There can be separate “instances” of the type in that we can allocate many variables of that type which can be passed as parameters to the methods contained in the module

Comment: Thank you very much.That's what I want.